# Many HTTP requests cause Bottle server failure

Tags: python, sockets, bottle

I have a following code:

```
@route('/my_page')
def my_page():
    conn = sqlite.connect('test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("select * from table")
    res = c.fetchall()
    c.close()
    out = template('my_page',rows=res)
    return out
```

and a template *my_page.tpl* with autorefresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

I open *http://my_server:8080/my_page* in my browser and after couple of refreshes my app gets stucked with following error:

```
File "c:\python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 116, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "c:\python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I need to restart my application to make it work again. I have also checked *netstat -ano* and I see many **TIME_WAIT** TCP connections. What causes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottle default server is not intended for production deployment. To increase stability and performance it is recommended to [switch the server backend](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#switching-the-server-backend).